# Como hago para que las palabras que ingresa el usuario reemplacen algunas letras en forma horizontal en la matriz de 20x20 en una posición aleatoria?

Tags: c#, matrices

> Pido las palabras al usuario en el main

```
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("Escriba la primera palabra: ");
        string palabra1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("Escriba la segunda palabra: ");
        string palabra2 = Console.ReadLine();
```

> Método con la matriz 20x20

```
        int filas = 20;
        int columnas = 20;

        string [,] letras = new string[filas, columnas];

        Random ran = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < filas; j++)
            {
                letras[i, j] += (char)ran.Next(65, 91);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < letras.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < letras.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(letras[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```

Como puedo hacer para reemplazar unas letras de la matriz 20x20 por la palabra que ingresa el usuario de forma vertical y en una posición aleatoria?

[image: Necesito que quede algo así]

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para q se te entienda mejor

Comment: Ahi actualicé la pregunta con una captura de como debería quedar

Answer (score 0):

Primero, ya generas de manera aleatoria la matriz, bien!.

Ahora debes generar de forma aleatoria donde deseas colocar la palabra.
¡Eso es todo!
Pero la pregunta es, ¿Cómo?!

Bueno acá un algoritmo para que coloques solo una palabra de manera aleatoria en la matriz.

```
ponerPalabraRandom(string[,] letras, string palabra) {
    // Declaramos las posiciones iniciales random
    int ranFila = ran.Next(0, 19); // generamos un randon del 1 al 20 pero en posiciones para la fila
    int ranColumna = ran.Next(0, 19); // generamos un randon del 1 al 20 pero en posiciones para la columna

    // Recorremos cada letra de la palabra ingresada
    for(int iChar = 0; iChar < palabra.Length; iChar++) {
        int i = ranFila; // Declaramos el contador de fila en el random inicial
        if(i == letras.GetLength(0)) { // Verificamos si el contador de Fila se pasa del máximo de filas, entonces regresamos a la posición 0.
            i = 0;
        }
        for(i; i < letras.GetLength(0); i++) { // Empezamos a recorrer las filas donde se inicio el random o en la posición 0.
            for(int y = ranColumna; y < letras.GetLength(1); y++) { // Solo el primer bucle recorre las columnas donde se inicio el random
                letras[i, y] = palabra[iChar];
            }
            ranColumna = 0; // reiniciamos el randon de columna una vez se termina de recorrer el primer bucle, luego cada recorrido de columnas siempre iniciara en 0 para tener continuidad
        }
    }
}
```

Esta función te va colocar una palabra random, pero ahora necesitas saber para la segunda palabra donde se ha colocado la primera para que no la reemplaces.

Eso puedes hacer guardando una pista de dicho inicio y fin de la palabra primera, en ese sentido vuelves hacer el algoritmo solo que verificando el número randon que estas generando.

Suerte con eso, espero este algoritmo te ayude en algo, si necesitas ayuda con guardas la posición inicial y final de la primera palabra, puedes colocarlo, pero primero intentalo.